# Tabs creating another window

Tags: javascript, html

I have a Main HTML page Which loads another HTML page based on the user action.The problem is when I click OK (submit) or Cancel another window is opened with same HTML.If I Comment the tab part its working fine,But I need tabs for other

Here is my HTML page(contains tabs) which gets loaded on user action
:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function tabs(selectedtab) {    
    // contents
    var s_tab_content = "tab_content_" + selectedtab;   
    //alert(s_tab_content);
    var contents = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
    for(var x=0; x<contents.length; x++) {
        name = contents[x].getAttribute("name");
        if (name == 'tab_content') {
            if (contents[x].id == s_tab_content) {
            contents[x].style.display = "block";                        
            } else {
            contents[x].style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    }   
}
</script>
<html>
    <body>
        <div  id="tab1"  name="tab" style="cursor: pointer; cursor: hand; width:90px;float: left;height: 22px ; margin-top: 0px;
        background-color:lightgrey;font-size: 13px;text-align: center;border-bottom: none;display: table-cell;"             onClick="tabs(1)">
            <div style="margin-top: 3px" >Tab1</div>
        </div>
        <div   id="tab2" name="tab" style="cursor: pointer; cursor: hand; width:90px;background-color:lightgrey;float: left;height: 20px; margin-top: 2px; font-size: 12px;text-align: center" onClick="tabs(2)">
            <div style="margin-top: 3px">Tab2</div>
        </div>
        <div style="width:auto;height: 22px; border-bottom-color: white;border-bottom-style: solid;border-bottom-width: 1px"></div>  

        <div name="tab_content" id="tab_content_1"  style="display: block; margin-left:20px;" >
            <br></br>   
            <br></br>   
            <div id="legendReport">
            XXXX:
            </div>
            <textarea id="r1"  name="textArea1" rows="4" value="" cols="50"></textarea> 
            <br></br>   
            <br></br>   
            <div id="legendRough">
            YYYY:
            </div>
            <textarea id="r2" name="textArea2" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>    
        </div> 

        <div name="tab_content" id="tab_content_2"  class="tab_content" style="display: none;margin-left:20px;">
            <br></br>   
            <br></br>                    
            <textarea id="r3" name="textArea3" rows="4" cols="50" ></textarea>  
            <br></br>   
            <br></br>   
            <textarea id="r4" name="textArea4" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>  
            <br></br>   
            <br></br>
            <br></br>   
            <br></br>
        </div>
        <div id="legendInfo"></div>
        <div id="analysisPointDisplay"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please attach the code for your `OK/CANCEL` buttons

Comment: Actually on click of OK I am creating XML data & saving it.

Comment: So maybe your webbrowser is downloading the XML file and just open it? Try to test returning some file with another extension

Comment: NO ,My web browser doesn't download.I am just creating data in XML format & saving it in to other field  in HTML